# What is the physical meaning of an LC circuit having a negative transfer function?

Tags: math, transfer-function, passive-networks

Say you have an ideal LC circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXji7b.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The transfer function of this circuit is a complex voltage divider: $$ \frac{\frac{1}{sC}}{sL + \frac{1}{sC}} $$ $$ \frac{1}{s^2LC + 1} $$ $$ \frac{1}{1-\omega^2LC} $$

That means that for large values of C, L, and/or \$\omega\$, the transfer function becomes negative. What physical meaning does this have? Does the signal go 180 degrees out of phase with the input? Am I perhaps missing a magnitude sign somewhere?

Comment: Yup, goes negative at high frequency for common values of L and C.  This is a 180 degree phase shift. Quite interesting how there is no imaginary part-- never looked at it like that before.

Comment: @ScottSeidman there's no imaginary part because there is no resistance in the circuit.

Comment: @Andyaka  If we could get that s raised to the third power, we'd have an imaginary part. Is there no way to do this without a resistor?  Doesn't an inductor parallel to the resistor do it?

Comment: @ScottSeidman it's to do with even orders of filters - even orders theoretically don't have to have a resistive "element" to the equation but odd orders do I reckon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does the signal go 180 degrees out of phase with the input?

Yes it does - that's what the negative implies

At resonance (\$\omega = \dfrac {1}{\sqrt{LC}}\$) the phase angle passes through -90º from 0º on its way to 180º.

It's also interesting to note that at resonance the formula becomes infinite in value too because there is no damping in the circuit to restrict it.

How does the voltage across C become infinite? It's because the input impedance to the series combination of L and C (at resonance) is zero and therefore infinite current flows. Totally impractical of course and the more regular analysis is done with a series R added: -

\$\dfrac{Vc}{Vin}\$ = \$\dfrac{\frac{1}{LC}}{s^2 + s\frac{R}{L} + \frac{1}{LC}}\$

Where \$\frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}\$ is the natural resonant frequency.

This time, at resonance the denominator has \$j\omega \frac{R}{L}\$ left in the formula. Here's what the amplitude and phase response looks like: -

[image]

R I've chosen to be 1\$\Omega\$, L is 100uH and C is 25nF. It peaks (because R is quite low) at over 30dB but you can see the phase does all the interesting stuff at close to resonance where it shifts 180º over a small range of frequencies.

Comment: Thanks. I've forgotten a lot of school, apparently! It's starting to come back. Transfer function has magnitude and direction, just like any vector. Magnitude is gain, direction is phase shift.

Comment: @StephenCollings glad to be of assistance dude